# Wordpress add rewrite URL look like WPML

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Same as title, i want visit link:

```
mysite.domain/hello-word
mysite.domain/my_slug/hello-word
```

is same link, look like WPML:

```
mysite.domain/hello-word
mysite.domain/en/hello-word
```

I try:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/?/([^/]*)/?', 'index.phptheme_var=$matches[0]&pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%theme_var%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

but not working, somebody can help me?

Comment: Can you refer this link https://rtcamp.com/blogger-to-wordpress/tutorials/user-guide/permalinks-and-slugs/

Answer (score 0):

Do you forgot question sign?

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/?/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?theme_var=$matches[0]&pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Between index.php and theme_var